# Terraform provisioner file .ppk file read error windows 11

Tags: terraform, provisioning

When I run "terraform apply" from windows 11, getting the below error message. Against the error message, I have the .ppk file available in my location. Can someone help me out if it is related to some ssh config issue?

Version details:

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 1.0.0"
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 3.63"
     }
  }
}


Error: file provisioner error
    │
    │   with null_resource.copy_ec2_keys,
    │   on c4-07-ec2bastion-provisioners.tf line 14, in resource "null_resource" "copy_ec2_keys":
    │   14:   provisioner "file" {
    │
    │ Failed to read ssh private key: no key found
```

Below is my provisioners code

```
# Create a Null Resource and Provisioners
resource "null_resource" "copy_ec2_keys" {
  depends_on = [module.ec2_public]
  # Connection Block for Provisioners to connect to EC2 Instance
  connection {
    type     = "ssh"
    host     = aws_eip.bastion_eip.public_ip    
    user     = "ec2-user"
    password = ""
    private_key = file("private-key/eks-terraform-key.ppk")
  }  

## File Provisioner: Copies the terraform-key.ppk file to /tmp/terraform-key.ppk
  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "private-key/eks-terraform-key.ppk"
    destination = "/tmp/eks-terraform-key.ppk"
  }
## Remote Exec Provisioner: Using remote-exec provisioner fix the private key permissions on Bastion Host
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "sudo chmod 400 /tmp/eks-terraform-key.ppk"
    ]
  }
## Local Exec Provisioner:  local-exec provisioner (Creation-Time Provisioner - Triggered during Create Resource)
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo VPC created on `date` and VPC ID: ${module.vpc.vpc_id} >> creation-time-vpc-id.txt"
    working_dir = "local-exec-output-files/"
    #on_failure = continue
  }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried converting your SSH key to PEM format ?

Comment: @AmineZaine yes it works now.. after converting the ".ppk" file to ".pem" file using "puttyGen"

Answer (score 0):

Terraform requires private keys to be provided in the PEM private key format, and so it's looking for a line resembling the following in whatever file you specify:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
```

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

```
-----EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

The error included in the question is what Terraform would produce if it didn't find a PEM section like this inside the given file. That suggests that the file is in some other format which Terraform doesn't support.